# cite in subfloat problem

Tags: citing, subfloats

I am using images taken from some other papers in my article. I would like to be able to cite the images in `\subfloat`, but `latex` generates error message. Here is the code snippet,

```
\newcommand{\figDWidth}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \subfloat[Bley et al.~\cite{Bley}]{\label{Ch.Background.Fig.1:a}\includegraphics[width=\figDWidth]{./Figures/Bley.jpg}}~
    \subfloat[Jang et al.~\cite{Jang}]{\label{Ch.Background.Fig.1:b}\includegraphics[width=\figDWidth]{./Figures/Jang.jpg}}
    \label{Ch.Background.Fig.1}
\end{figure}
```

and error message,

```
Illegal parameter number in definition of \sf@captionlist. ...gDWidth]{./Figures/Bley.jpg}}
```

Comment: `\cite` may need to be "protected": `\protect\cite{...}`.

Comment: Curiously, what package are you using?  The current 'best' package for subfloats is now [`subcaption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) which improves on `subfig`.